# How to find Laplace Transform of fractional-order differential systems

Tags: laplace-transform

Let us consider the fractional-order complex-valued dynamic system as

$D^\alpha z(t)=-Az(t)+Bz(t-\tau),\ z\in \mathbb{C}$.

How to find the characteristic equation and the Laplace transformation?

Comment: There are several ways to define solutions to delay equations. Maybe you can add some lines indicating what space of initial values you consider and how existence, uniqueness, continuous dependence and exponential boundedness of your solutions is established.